# timeout/stopping scipy curve_fit in a thread

Tags: python, scipy, python-multithreading

I have a GUI in which a python thread performs a scipy.curve_fit call. This can sometimes take a while and I would like to limit it to a certain time limit. If it takes longer than this I would like the thread to raise and error or return a default value.

I have searched around for different ways to do this. I can't make the thread regularly check for a timeout variable as when it starts running the curve_fit call it won't do anything else till it is finished.

Obviously this problem is not restricted to the curve_fit function but any library function that could take a long time to return, which I put in a thread.

Is this the best way to kill the thread?:
[Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

Is there a better more Pythonic way of doing this that I am missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Specifically on curve fitting, some of the functions can be passed a maximum number of function evaluations, which will limit the time used by the fitting routing.  One example is leastsq() can be passed maxfev.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this parameter but haven't yet tried using it. I think this might be a bit tricky as depending on which function I am fitting and how many parameters I have the value for maxfev would be different for different calls. I think it would still be nicer if I had a way of timing out the thread.

Comment: On the other hand, you are asking for a calculation to be done, and are apparently trying to give the user an out if it is 'taking too long' - to me this means that the absolute value of maxfev isn't very important, just that the call will return within ~10 seconds on an 'average' machine.